# XMLHttpRequest cannot load url. Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Tags: php, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make an ajax request to my restserver:

```
<script>
var id = "104";
var postData = {
  'id' : id
};
AJS.$.ajax({
     url: "myurl",
     crossDomain: true,
     data: postData,
     type: "DELETE",
     // dataType: "json",
     success: function(msg, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
     }
});
</script>
```

But I am receiving the following error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http ://myurl/rest/controller/resource/id/107. Method DELETE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

I have added the following at the top of my php controller:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-requested-with');
```

The only methods it seems to accept is get and post but delete and put create an error.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Did you get this working. It appears the browser ignores the Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Comment: Yes, using the below method, also using Laravel now.

Answer (score 0):

I learned the hard way the other day that it's pretty much impossible to perform a cross-domain ajax request from just about any browser. I would handle the redirecting HTTP request on the server-side instead. Have this ajax request go to a script on the same url/server, and have that script perform an HTTP request and wait for the data from the other server you're attempting to get data from.

Comment: Hi Jacob, interesting thought. I do have POST and GET working, my consideration was that if POST was working I could perhaps send a hidden field that would respond to DELETE and PUT methods?

The other thing is, how would you write an AJAX request to another script, or even pass parameters from one script to another script on another server. Its a good idea, but sounds taxing to write :)